# How to find number of links and print them, when mouse is hovering a element in UFT?

Tags: testing, functional-testing, hp-uft, uft14

Recently I came across fireevent and I tried to implement it on the website of Flipkart. I was trying to use firevent("onmouseover") for the link.

I searched for mobiles in the search box and took the number of links on that page, then we can see electronics, TVs & appliances, men, women, etc. when the mouse is hovering on these names I can see some items with names which are links internally. So, I want how many those links are there when the mouse is hovering on electronics, TVs & appliances, men, women, etc and print them.

I googled a lot for these and I could not find any useful resource for this.

Please Help me solve the above problem.